# Can't download or view PDF and document files such as Word and Excel in my webview

Tags: android, excel, pdf, ms-word

I have created a project using webview in android studio, Everything is working fine except some errors.

1. Can't view or download XML or PDF files.
2. Current webpage goes to  home page when I change orientation of device.
3. Progressbar works on only front webpage.

Please help me.

I am trying to sort these out for last one week.

Thank you.

**MainActivity Java codes**

```
package com.xxxxxxx.xxxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView mywebview;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.pccegoa.org");
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

       mywebview.getSettings();
       setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        mywebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mywebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mywebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
    }

     @Override
      public void onBackPressed (){
    if(mywebview.canGoBack()) mywebview.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
     }
      }
```

**ourViewClient java file**

```
    package com.xxxxxxxx.xxxx;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url)
    {
    v.loadUrl(url);
    return true;}}
```

**activity_Main file**

```
  <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"        android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  
   </WebView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: To get an answer here, always show your code! Show, what you've already done to solve your problem. Nobody will write code for you.

Comment: OK Friend. I will upload..actually I'm using mobile app to post the question.